# AngularDart class has no instance getter 'isLoggedIn'

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I've got the following code in my AngularDart application:

```dart
DuseClient get client {
  var _client = new DuseClient(
  Uri.parse("https://duse.herokuapp.com/v1"),
  new ClientClientFactory());
  if (!_client.isLoggedIn) {
    _client.token = window.localStorage["token"];
  }
  return _client;
}
```

It should be fine, all the called methods are part of the `DuseClient` class, but if I execute the code, the following error is displayed:

```
Exception: Class 'DuseClient' has no instance getter 'isLoggedIn'.
```

I know this has to be somehow related to the AngularDart transformer. In [an other post](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1137) it was mentioned that one should use a map syntax, but I plan don't have access to the Module/Angular scope because I plan to inject the created client into the AngularDart application. Anybody got an idea how to get around this error? For further reference, the GitHub repository containing the error is [here](https://github.com/duse-io/duseapp).

Comment: If you say the `DuseClient` class has the `isLoggedIn` getter then there isn't anything wrong with your code and without more context I is probably impossible to make conclusions. Can you please at least add links to these "other posts" to make it more clear what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry for that. I updated the question with the link to the corresponding post and an additional link to the repository containing the error.

Comment: Seems the related post is a different issue. I can't see expressions dynamically created in your question. What action in your app leads to the error?

Comment: As soon as the line with `if (!client.isLogged) ...` is run the error occurs. This line is contained in the setup of the app, during the constructor of the module. The client should be injected via

`bind(DuseClient,
          withAnnotation: const DuseClientConfig(),
          toValue: client);`

Comment: I launched your app and didn't get an error.

Comment: I deleted the packages folder and ran pub get again but I'm still receiving the error... The error appears right away when starting the app with the DartEditor. Do you start the app via command line?

Comment: I start it with WebStorm but that shouldn't make a difference. You could try to delete the `.pub` folder and run `pub cache repair`

Comment: You are right: If I run the app from command line via pub serve, the error doesn't appear, but in DartEditor the error occurs. It has to be related to the flags the editor specifies.

Comment: You can enter `about:version` or `chrome:version` (in the browsers URL bar) to see the used command line flags.

Comment: I also tried with DartEditor and don't any error.

Comment: After your suggested actions (deleting .pub, `pub cache repair`) it's running fine again! Thanks for that blazingly fast answer.

Comment: Did you update Dart recently? If yes to which version?

Comment: Yes, I updated it yesterday to 1.9.0-dev7.1